# Javascript - regex to validate document files - PDF, TXT, DOC

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-file-upload

I'm using blueimp File Upload plugin to upload files. There's an example regex to restrict the upload to images only:

```
var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
```

How can I change this to upload image files, and documents like PDF, TXT, DOC?

Comment: Is it not working now? If so, what errors/unexpected results? If it is working and you just want to add extensions, just add it to the group of ORs (`[..]png|pdf|txt|doc)$`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var acceptFileTypes =
/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$|^application\/(pdf|msword)$|^text\/plain$/i;
```

This seems to assume that the correct mime type is checked against `acceptFileTypes`

Comment: i would just like to contribute to the above for future references, since this was answered in 2014: msword matches for .doc filetypes. for docx, filetype is: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: Also watch out for ppt(x), xls(x): [PPTX: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation] and [XLSX: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet]

Answer (score 1):

```
var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|txt)$/i;
```

and make sure that these files are kept inside the image folder. so the full path to the text file should be something like `/image/dsds/file.txt`

if you want to add your own folder name it accordingly

Comment: dude any and every extension can be supported just add it with a `|` . pdf|img|papa|mummy|bro|sis etc  :D

Comment: @explosion-pills answer is the correct one - one needs to add the additional MIME types